# ios prototype tableviewcell preview not matching build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to create a view similar to the clock app alarm view. I created a custom TableViewController and TableViewCell similar to the getting started app that apple provides. I added a stack view to the prototype cell and added constraints for leading, trailing, top, bottom to = the superView and the storyboard preview looks how I want it to but when I build it, everything is squished in the top left corner. How do I fix this?
 Thanks.

**preview**
[image: preview]

**build**
[image: build]

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: maybe your table view has no valid constraints to fill up the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed these steps to form the output

- First I dragged the 2 labels and 1 switch on to the cell and arranged them like
  you shown in preview (please note that I didnot apply any other constraints just drag them to their positions)
- Secondly, I embedded the label1 and label2 inside a vertical stackview
- Thirdly, I embedded the above stackview and switch inside a horizontal stackview
- Lastly I added the top, left , right, bottom spacing to zero in add new
  constraints menu to this parent stackview

So I achieved the following result

[image]

Comment: In the table view did you use static cells or dynamic prototypes? Because when I try out a layout like you with static cells it looks fine but when I try to use dynamic prototypes it messes up like my photo

Comment: I updated my answer please check, please tell me if you face any problem.@EdwardRichman

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Since you got it to work I decided to try rewriting my code and it ended up working fine. I still dont know why the original code didnt work. I would upvote your answer if I had the ability